# Converting Number to Specific Culture from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. My app has a Razor view that generates some JavaScript. That block of code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model == null)
{
  var amount = 0;
}
else
{
  <text>var amount = @Convert.ToString(Model.DailyAmount.Value);</text>
}
...
</script>
```

When a user's culture is set to Germany ("de-DE"), the view gets rendered as:
    
      var amount = 0,00;

`DailyAmount` is a `decimal?` Notice how the value that gets rendered (`0,00`) has a comma to represent a decimal. However, I want to always render the value as 0.00 instead. How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify exact culture for your amount - i.e.:

```
@Convert.ToString(Model.DailyAmount.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```